# Generic constraints -- I'm not sure how to fix this situation with an either/or case

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, icomparable, generic-constraints

Basically I have the following:

```
public static bool IsBetween<T>(this T value, T a, T b)
    where T : IComparable
{
    ...
}

public static bool IsBetween<T>(this T value, T a, T b)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    ...
}
```

The problem is I can't do this because you can't have a member with the same signature, even if the constraints are different. But, there is no way to state that the constraint is either `IComparable` OR `IComparable<T>`. So, I'm not sure what to do here outside of just picking one and going with it. And, no matter which one I pick I'm losing out on the other because they are separate and don't inherit from each other (which makes sense).

Am I missing something here in that is there a way to accomplish using both, or am I going to have to pick one (probably the generic version)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't understand why the first method is generic at all. Why isn't it just:

```
public static bool IsBetween(this IComparable value, IComparable left, IComparable right)
```

What value does making the method generic add? Obviously you're not going to avoid the boxing penalty because the values are going to be boxed when you call `CompareTo(object)`.

Unless you have some compelling reason to make the method generic, don't make it generic. It then has a different signature from the other method, and your problem is solved.

Comment: I never really thought about it like that. I guess it was because I started off with the generic version, then copied/pasted it and attempted to just do a quick change.

Comment: Also, will this default to select the `IComparable<T>` option first, and the `IComparable` option second?

Comment: @m-y: Overload resolution will choose the *more specific* method. If there's no way to determine which one is more specific then you'll get an ambiguity error.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET method resolution overload doesn't take into account return types and generic constraints. So even if `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` had something in common that would still not work. Just pick the `IComparable<T>` version. Standard .NET types such as Int32, Decimal, DateTime, ... implement both interfaces anyway.

Comment: That's what I figured, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something here. I will end up going with the generic version. I was just hoping to have my method be available for other code that implements only `IComparable` and not both (or just `IComparable<T>`).